# how to access private CocoaPod repo hosted on azure devops on app center for automatic build?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, private-pod

I have configured App Center CI on develop branch that is hosted on Azure Devops. Develop branch has Podfile that includes a dependency for custom component as private CocoaPod hosted on same project's Azure repo where main app code located.
Problem is that App center build failed and shows below error.

```
 Cloning into '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/d20200428-1203-er05me'...
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://xxxxxx@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
##[error]The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[error]The 'pod' command failed with error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Pod install
```

Looks like its does not have access to private cocoapod repo that is hosted on Same location where Develop branch repo. I don't know how to give access to another repo access(private pod) on access on app center.

Comment: Is this about Azure Visual Studio AppCenter? Or IBM MobileFirst Application Center?

Comment: Its Azure Visual Studio AppCenter.

Comment: How did you fixed it? I'm with a similar problem